# Dropdown list strangely shown out of the table

Tags: php, html

I'm having some issues right now with some weird behaviour of my code and can't find the why.

I have a table of extensions (phone) which are assigned to a qeue. I get the data by SQL query and then show it in the screen.
One of the data shown is Priority which I want to be changed with jquery+ajax via choosing a new one of a dropdown list.

So, I managed this code:

```
echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="30%" id="deletion" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="border:1px solid #cccccc;">
        <tr>
            <th><strong>Extension</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Priority</strong></th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>';
        while ($datos_extension = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo '<tr id="'.$extension_data['id'].'"><td>'.$extension_data['extension'].'</td><td>'.show_priority($datos_extension['priority']).'</td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr>';
            }
        echo "</table>";
```

Now, the function:

```
function show_priority ($priority) {
    $max_priority = 3;
    $cont = 1;

    echo '<select name="priority" class="priority">';

    while ($cont <= $max_priority) {
        echo '<option';
        if ($cont == $priority)
            echo " selected";
        echo ' value="'.$cont.'">'.$cont.'</option>';
        $cont ++;
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

But it shows the Dropdowns out of the table... Here is the HTML output:

```
<tr>
            <th><strong>Extension</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Priority</strong></th>

            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><select name="priority" class="priority"><option selected value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><tr id="2"><td>1002</td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr><select name="priority" class="priority"><option selected value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><tr id="3"><td>1003</td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr><select name="priority" class="priority"><option selected value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><tr id="4"><td>1004</td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr><select name="priority" class="priority"><option selected value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><tr id="5"><td>1005</td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr><select name="priority" class="priority"><option selected value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><tr id="6"><td>1006</td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr><select name="priority" class="priority"><option selected value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><tr id="7"><td>1007</td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr><select name="priority" class="priority"><option selected value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><tr id="8"><td>1008</td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr><select name="priority" class="priority"><option selected value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><tr id="9"><td>1009</td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr><select name="priority" class="priority"><option value="1">1</option><option selected value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><tr id="10"><td>9003</td><td></td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr></table>
```

Do someone knows where it could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of nested echo statements. So before PHP caches first echo it displays second one, because it's inside. I think that solution is to build string inside of `show_priority` function and just return it, like:

```
function show_priority ($priority) {
    $max_priority = 3;
    $cont = 1;

    $return = '<select name="priority" class="priority">';

    while ($cont <= $max_priority) {
        $return .= '<option';
        if ($cont == $priority)
            $return .= " selected=selected"; //this should be done like this in proper HTML
        $return .= ' value="'.$cont.'">'.$cont.'</option>';
        $cont ++;
    }
    $return .= "</select>";

    return $return;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it I believe it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

It's because all code for `echo` gets executed before outputting the final sting. The function echoes the list before the parent `echo` populates the table row. You need to change your function like this to be able to insert it into other strings:

```
function show_priority ($priority) {
    $max_priority = 3;
    $cont = 1;
    $output = '';

    $output .= '<select name="priority" class="priority">';

    while ($cont <= $max_priority) {
        $output .= '<option';
        if ($cont == $priority)
            $output .= " selected";
        $output .= ' value="'.$cont.'">'.$cont.'</option>';
        $cont ++;
    }
    $output .= "</select>";
    return $output;
}
```

But after all it's always better to return the list as an array or an object, and then populate it separately after you generated all contents; separate database logic from design.

Also if for some reason you can't alter the function you could use output buffering:

```
    while ($datos_extension = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            ob_start();
            show_priority($datos_extension['priority']);
            echo '<tr id="'.$extension_data['id'].'"><td>'.$extension_data['extension'].'</td><td>'.ob_get_clean().'</td><td><a href="#" class="delete negative button"><span class="cross icon"></span>Delete</a></td></tr>';
   }
```